# BeautifulSoup to get first value using string/text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

[Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is handy for html parsing in python, but I meet problem to have clean code to get the value directly using `string` or `text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tr ="""    
<table>
    <tr><td>text1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text2<div>abc</div></td></tr>
</table>
"""
table = BeautifulSoup(tr,"html.parser")
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    td = row.findAll("td")
    print td[0].text
    print td[0].string
```

result:

```
text1
text1
text2abc
None
```

How can I get the result for

```
text1
text2
```

I want to skip the extra inner tag

`beautifulsoup4-4.5.0` is used with `python 2.7`

Comment: `td[0].contents[0]` should give you what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    td = row.findAll("td")
    t = td[0]
    print t.contents[0]
```

But that will only work if you are always looking for the text *before* the div tag

Comment: fit well for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the [`.find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) function by setting the `text` and [`recursive`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) argument.

```
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    td1 = row.td.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    print str(td1)
```

You'll get your output as:

```
text1
text2
```

This will work regardless of the position of the `div` tag. See the example below.

```
>>> tr ="""    
<table>
    <tr><td>text1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text2<div>abc</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div>abc</div>text3</td></tr>
</table>
"""
>>> table = BeautifulSoup(tr,"html.parser")
>>> for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        td1 = row.td.find(text=True, recursive=False)
        print str(td1)


text1
text2
text3
```

Comment: this is good as well,  and `recursive=False` is very useful for me in other case.